# C# Random Question

Tags: c#, random

I  have two different  realization random  function:

Version 1:

```
  public double myRnd()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            return rnd.NextDouble();
        }                


            //-- Generate Random Number for Delaer
            double DealersCard = myRnd();

            //-- Generate Players  4 Random Number
            double Box1Card = myRnd();
            double Box2Card = myRnd();
            double Box3Card = myRnd();
            double Box4Card = myRnd();
```

version 2:

```
       //-- Create  Random  Object 
        var rnd = new Random();

        //-- Generate Random Number for Delaer
        double DealersCard = rnd.NextDouble();

        //-- Generate Players  4 Random Number
        double Box1Card = rnd.NextDouble();
        double Box2Card = rnd.NextDouble();
        double Box3Card = rnd.NextDouble();
        double Box4Card = rnd.NextDouble();
```

Which method  is better  ?

Comment: Old question about the problems in your first version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-not-working-the-way-i-had-planned-c

Comment: You represent cards as doubles?

Comment: Well, it doesn't really matter which one you use.  You'll get the exact same random number back in version 1.  That cannot affect the outcome, you need to shuffle the deck first.  So using the exact same random number from a shuffled deck doesn't matter.  I recommend 4, chosen by a fair roll of a die.

Answer (score 9):

Version 2 is *much* better. Version 1 is totally broken.

Version 1 recreates `Random` for each number. `Random` is seeded by `Environment.TickCount` which changes only every 1-16ms. So you will get the same random number for all calls to `myRnd` in that time interval.

In addition version 2 is faster since it doesn't need to recreate `Random`.

---

Similar questions have been asked quite often, usually by people who implemented version 1 and wondered why it doesn't for. For example: [Random number generator only generating one random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-not-working-the-way-i-had-planned-c)

The MSDN documentation for `Random` states:

> The random number generation starts from a seed value. If the same seed is used repeatedly, the same series of numbers is generated. One way to produce different sequences is to make the seed value time-dependent, thereby producing a different series with each new instance of Random. By default, the parameterless constructor of the Random class uses the system clock to generate its seed value, while its parameterized constructor can take an Int32 value based on the number of ticks in the current time. However, because the clock has finite resolution, using the parameterless constructor to create different Random objects in close succession creates random number generators that produce identical sequences of random numbers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx

---

I've filed an [improvement request on Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/678547/improve-seeding-in-the-default-constructor-of-random) since this is a very common mistake.

Comment: Your improvement is for sure an improvement; but how does one implement it without breaking "two runs of the same app gives different randoms"?

Comment: @Captain I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: In c++ it is: rand() gets the same value for srand(time(Now)) thats well defined. I think the same contract is at the c# corner

Comment: I only proposed changing the parameterless constructor of `Random`. This will not affect users who supply a seed to get deterministic sequences. I don't think there is a contractual obligation for `new Random()` to use the time for seeding.

Comment: I'm still very interested in any solution you might have

Comment: I don't really see what your problem is.

Comment: @CodeInChaos let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1334/discussion-between-captain-giraffe-and-codeinchaos)

Answer (score 1):

The first one doesn't work very well.

The point in *any* random function is that it is pseudo-random, and the random value you get depends on the seed. When you create the `Random` object, it is seeded with the current time.

So when you create a new `Random` object every time you want a random number, you end up seeding with the current time again and again, which might result in getting the same numbers repeatedly (because the current time might not have changed, depending on the accuracy and resolution of the timer it uses).

The `Random` class is used to create one object, from which you can get *a sequence* of random numbers.